# Objects places opposite partly in particle system

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine

I am making grass field and part of my grass group for particle have object placed up side down.
I tried to rotate the up side down object too but still it doesn't rotate when used in particle. How can I fix the rotation?

[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 3):

I found out!
If I apply rotation and scale, then it works.

[image]
[image]