# Particle System Makes Objects All Lay Horizontally With The Same Rotation

Tags: particles

I'm trying to make a grass particle system, however when I select the group of grass clumps, they are all laying down. When I set the "Initial Rotation" to "None" instead of "Velocity/Hair" the grass is up the right way but "Phase" and "Random" under Rotation doesn't do anything so all the grass is facing the same way. Another person had a similar issue and the response said to change "Normal" under "Velocity" to 1 and "Z" to 1, this however only increases the size of my grass objects. A lot of other sliders in the particle settings also increase the size when I don't think they should. Anyone know why this is and how to fix it?

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/65701/objects-places-opposite-partly-in-particle-system and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/72448/how-do-i-make-custom-grass-using-particles and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/8104/rotate-group-objects-outwards-on-spherical-particle-system and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/109776/blades-of-grass-didnt-turn-out-what-i-wanted/109818#109818 and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/91395/hair-emitter-particles-point-in-random-directions/91397#91397

Comment: @cegaton thank you so much! Idk how I didn't find any of these. Looks like I needed to rotate my grass object to face the x axis.

Comment: @cegaton all my grass still seems to face the same way though and phase/rotation won't do anything.

Comment: Please use the [edit] link at the bottom of your question (https://i.stack.imgur.com/lXFuK.png) and add more information on how you set up your project, the particle object and the particle settings. [Add images](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) that might help others understand.  See [How to upload an image to a post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491)